# Having trouble populating listbox from xml elements

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

The XML is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Folder_Settings>
  <Documents>Checked</Documents>
  <Pictures>Not Checked</Pictures>
  <Music>Checked</Music>
  <Videos>Not Checked</Videos>
  <Downloads>Checked</Downloads>
  <Contacts>Checked</Contacts>
  <Favorites>Not Checked</Favorites>
  <Other>Checked</Other>
  <OtherFolderSettings>C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\revouninstaller-portable</OtherFolderSettings>
  <OtherFolderSettings>D:\Personal Website</OtherFolderSettings>
  <OtherFolderSettings>D:\testing</OtherFolderSettings>
  <OtherFolderSettings>C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\revouninstaller-portable</OtherFolderSettings>
  <OtherFolderSettings>C:\Users\Asus\.eclipse</OtherFolderSettings>
</Folder_Settings>
```

I would like to take the information inside of OtherFolderSettings and populate it into a listbox. The code I am using sort of works, but it only adds the first two folders strings into the listbox. Thank you in advance for all help and advice.

Code:

```
 var applicationSettingsXML = new XmlDocument();
            var XMLFileStream = new FileStream("Settings.xml", FileMode.Open);
            applicationSettingsXML.Load(XMLFileStream);

            var folderList = applicationSettingsXML.GetElementsByTagName("Folder_Settings");
            for (var i = 0; i <= folderList.Count; i++)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add( applicationSettingsXML.GetElementsByTagName("OtherFolderSettings")[i].InnerText);

            }

            XMLFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Well you're iterating `folderList.Count + 1` times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because your loop is:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= folderList.Count; i++)
```

... where `folderList` is the list of `Folder_Settings` elements. There's only one of those, so you're iterating twice. It's a good job you don't actually use `folderList[i]`, because otherwise you'd be out of bounds on the second iteration. Loops like that should pretty much *always* use `<` rather than `<=`.

However, I would strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` - it makes everything much simpler. I'd also recommend using `foreach` loops whenever you can, too:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
foreach (var element in doc.Root.Elements("OtherFolderSettings))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(element.Value);
}
```

(Oh, and use `using` statements to close resources cleanly...)